# npx react-native init dont work because react-native-cli module is not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npx

[image]

I'm trying to create a project with React-Native (Without Expo) and I'm getting an error that it doesn't find the "react-native-cli" package. However, this should not be so because in the guide tells you that the react-native CLI gobla is already deprecated and instead use npx. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

PS: I already uninstalled react-native-cli

Comment: Did you uninstall `react-native-cli` and `@react-native-community/cli` globally?

Comment: Yes (I forgot to add that)